# DateTime.ToString throwing IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

I don't have time to investigate now so I am hoping someone can save some time for me when I will be back at work to have this one solved :) ...

Problem is simple yet puzzling.

I am getting IndexOutOfRangeException on this line of code:

```
var date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).ToString();
```

I can tell that date is created just fine, ToString() makes the problem.
The problem occurs after I make a change in CultureInfo on current thread:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(langCode);
```

Still, from a logical point of view that makes no sense to me.

Thanks, Michal

Comment: Whats the value of `langCode`?

Comment: langCode is "es-ES" for spanish in the case I tested ... but could be something else too ...

Comment: It works for me... Please post the exact and full code that pops the exception.

Comment: Is it throwing _Index_ OutOfRangeException or _Argument_ OutOfRangeException. According to the docs, the DateTime constructor (and `DateTime.ToString()`) throws ArgumentOORE. if you're getting IndexOORE, it's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: What is `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar` and `.MinSupportedDateTime` and `.MaxSupportedDateTime` on that `Calendar`?

Comment: Maybe constructing the culture with `new CultureInfo(langCode, false)` will help.

Comment: I think that the code above is really everything that is needed. It is an WP7 application, and within the app user can independently on the system language set the app language. Yes, it is an INDEXOutOfRangeException, not Argument :) .... and last, constructor of CultureInfo does not offer second parameter choice

Comment: [picture](http://i48.tinypic.com/214r3oy.png)

Comment: The code works for me as well. I stand by my original statement, nothing here would throw an IndexOORE. It's got to be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Actually the conclusion is that I did not verify input string correctly it was just "es". According to the image I posted above, when I used "es" instead of "es-ES", some internal datetime templates were tried to be read but there was nothing and it threw IndexOORE. In general it is still a bit strange that you can get this kind of error by simply putting datetime to string :)

Comment: Hi @frno, I am having exactly the same issue. So did you end up having two resources files one for es and the other for es-ES?